# Wait until dialog opens, then run

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript.

I'm working on a code that will programmatically click a button that opens a dialog box, and then enter some text to that dialog. The problem is that the DOM element with the text area doesn't exist before I click the button to open the dialog, so my code opens the dialog and then gives me an error for trying to enter the text into a nonexistent text area...

The code looks something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click(); // opens a dialog box
document.getElementsByName('message_body')[0].value = 'my text'; // enters text to dialog
```

It works when I run the first line, wait for the dialog box to load, and then run the second line. It doesn't work when I try to run both lines together.

**what I've tried so far**

I've tried using timeout:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[i].click(); setTimeout(document.getElementsByName('message_body')[0].value = 'my text',7000);
```

but the second line just gives the same error.

also tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[49].click(); 
setTimeout(1,7000);  
document.getElementsByName('message_body')[0].value = 'my text';
```

I get the same error.

I also tried a while that waits for the text box to be defined, this just get me browser stuck...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[49].click();     
while(document.getElementsByName('message_body')[0] == undefined){}
document.getElementsByName('message_body')[0].value = 'my text';
```

**my question**

Is there any way to get Javascript to run the "enter text" only after the dialog opened, so I don't get an error?

Comment: why don't you have the dizlog box in your DOM at the begining with css display none and just change the css property to css display block, like that you will be abble to acces to your textarea immediatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is very simple. I had to write the 'setTimeout' like so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click(); //open dialog box 
setTimeout(function() {document.getElementsByName('message_body')[0].value = 'my text';},500); // wait for 0.5 sec, than run.
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click(); //open dialog box 
    setTimeout(document.getElementsByName('message_body')[0].value = 'my text';,500); // wait for 0.5 sec, than run.
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not watching the DOM. Therefore when you add an element your code can't find the newly updated node element. A front end frame work like React or AngularJS will watch the DOM and be able to update the DOM as new elements are added or deleted. A front-end frame work is needed to watch the DOM and give you the desired effects.